# Does Microsoft provide paid support for SQL Express?

Tags: sql-server

For instance, if we run into any kind of issues with SQL Express, if we call Microsoft,  will the provide technical support?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any great documentation to back this up other than articles referring to SQL Server 2005 like this one [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165629(v=sql.90).aspx).

I also just tried to create a ticket for SQL Server Express, and the support site lists Express as an option. You can see for yourself by starting [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=ClassicCommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=15743&ccsid=636165666103211753). I've chosen support, developer or IT support, SQL Server, then SQL Server 2016 and finally the option for edition came up and I chose Express.

Microsoft provides support to customers of SQL Server express in the same manner as SQL Server Standard and Enterprise - if you have a support agreement with hours or pay for hours, you'll receive support. If an item is found to be a bug in the product, typically the case hours or money are refunded/not applied, if it is user error/application issue on your end/etc the hours are used like normal. SQL Server licenses of the paid versions don't automatically give you access to support. Support is a separate offering, effectively.

Comment: I just chat with Microsoft support - they do not provide support to free software.  The next question he asked was do I want to upgrade to a different edition.

Comment: Are you sure? They do. You can open a ticket for SQL Server Express. They don't provide free support for free (or paid) software, though.

And the upgrade question is really a separate and more involved one. Do you have sizing or performance requirements above Express? With SQL Server 2016 SP1, many of the features in enterprise you can code against are in Express, but it limits DB sizes and CPU/Memory/etc. So it really depends on your goals and needs. But I would look more into support, I'm fairly certain they do.

Comment: I should have saved that chat window but I'm pretty sure that's what the guy (Moses) from support told me.

Comment: I'm surprised that they did not offer paid per incident support. Did you have a specific question?  Why don't you post it here?